# Result identity changing

Tags: identity, tor

I'm using TOR and I want to know, how to switch between result-nodes with need country. I can simply change it by telnet the 9051 port like:

```
telnet localhost 9051
"AUTHENTICATE\r"
"signal NEWNYM\r"
"quit\r"
```

This will chose randomly the exit(result) node. My goal is to change that node to the node from need country. I didn't find such information in the documentation, but in some GUI apps for the TOR there is a map with a list of all available nodes/servers and their country, so that I can choose need one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
> telnet localhost 9051
AUTHENTICATE     
SETCONF ExitNodes={us}
SETCONF StrictNodes=1
SIGNAL NEWNYM
QUIT
```

Tor will only use exit nodes from the US in this case. The changes are *not* written to torrc. If you want to write them, use `SAVECONF`.

Comment: `StrictNodes` assures that Tor will only choose from the Exitnodes you set. If you set `StrictNodes` to 0 and not US-based node is available Tor would select some random other node. When set to 1 Tor will print an error message, if there is no US-based node.