# TOR - change identity on every request

Tags: php, networking, network-programming, tor

I would like to **force TOR change the IP** on **every request**. Or at least every few seconds.

Also, it would be great if the solution will work **both on Linux and Windows**.

Anyone knows how can I achieve this?

I found this PHP code which claims to be what I am looking for but I cannot understand what it is doing.

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen('127.0.0.1', 9051, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$auth_code = 'YOUR_PASSWORD';
if ($fp) {
    echo "Connected to TOR port<br />";
}
else {
    echo "Cant connect to TOR port<br />";
}

fputs($fp, "AUTHENTICATE \"".$auth_code."\"\r\n");
$response = fread($fp, 1024);
list($code, $text) = explode(' ', $response, 2);
if ($code = '250') {
    echo "Authenticated 250 OK<br />";
}
else {
    echo "Authentication failed<br />";
}

fputs($fp, "SIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n");
$response = fread($fp, 1024);
list($code, $text) = explode(' ', $response, 2);
if ($code = '250') {
    echo "New Identity OK<br />";
}
else {
    echo "SIGNAL NEWNYM failed<br />";
    die();       
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Somebody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It connects via Socket to your local tor relay, authenticates and sends a `SIGNAL NEWNYM`, which forces the tor relay to change the identity and exit node.

See more at

- [identity changing in tor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274462/result-identity-changing)
- [tor options](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en)

There is even a [SE site about tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/).